# Unexpected ClassCastException with findViewById

Tags: android, layout, classcastexception

I play around with the 'searchable dictionnary' to get into Android development.

My problem is that I get some `ClassCastException` when modifying the XML layouts.

My guess is that the R file is outdated, but what is weird is that I still have the problem even after recreating it.

Here are the releveant piece of code and log :

**The log file :**

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageButton
>   E/AndroidRuntime(  438):        at
>   eu.accleaner.android.WordActivity.onCreate(WordActivity.java:87)

**The incriminated line in the Activity :**

```
mDefinition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cheers,

Vincent

Answer (score 3):

From what it looks like, there's an ImageButton in the XML with an id of "definition", and you're trying to cast it to a TextView. Change your TextView cast to ImageButton.

Comment: This can often times be caused by resource ID values in `R.java` being out of sync with other precompiled classes. If you are using Eclipse, do a Project | Clean. If you are building from the command line, use `ant clean install` instead of just `ant install`.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue. R.java generates IDs based on android:id in xml:


`public static final int imageButton01=0x7f050001;

public static final int definition=0x7f050002;`

When I add new imagebutton R.java will update to


`public static final int imageButton01=0x7f050001;

public static final int imageButton02=0x7f050002;

public static final int definition=0x7f050003;`

Due to synchronization problem `R.id.definition` returns old ID `0x7f050002` in `mDefinition = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.definition);` But it corresponds to another element (ImageButton02) according to updated R.java.

So we have ClassCastException

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to fix: Assign some new 'id' value in Layout XML and findViewById().

It is most probably a bug.