# findViewById ClassCastExcpetion

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-extension

I'm using the kotlin-extension plugin for finding the views.

But now I get an exception by

```
setSupportActionBar(mainActivity_toolbar)
```

It worked until now, but now it gives an

```
ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
```

The last Thing I did, was to add an id to my fab and set an `OnClickListener`.

But in my layout.xml:

`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` has the id `"@+id/mainActivity_toolbar"`
and `FrameLayout` has the id `"@+id/mainActivity_framelayout"`.

I first thought there is a bug in the kotlin-extension plugin, but with `findViewById` it doesn't work either.

Thank you

Comment: post your layout xml and code .

Comment: Please post larger pieces of your code to provide some context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restarting IntelliJ solved my problem.

Didn't thought on that, only rebuilt my Project and that didn't helped.

Due to this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7731317/7441041), I thought this could be my problem, so because rebuilt dosn't helped, I restartet IntelliJ and it worked.